# Deleting multiple files in flutter

Tags: flutter

In ApplicationDiretory , i create finalImage_{$DateTime.Now()} files , i need to delete them .
I need to delete the files starts with the name finalImage_* are present in tempDirectory,

```
Below is the snippet which deletes all files    
 final cacheDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
     if (cacheDir.existsSync()) {
       cacheDir.deleteSync(recursive: true);

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```dart
final cacheDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    if (cacheDir.existsSync()) {
      cacheDir.list(recursive: false).forEach((file) {
        String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;
        if (fileName.contains("finalImage_")) file.deleteSync(recursive: true);
      });
    }
```